# How to document RSQL filters in swagger doc?

Tags: swagger, openapi, springfox, rsql

I looked if there is any out of the box or an extension support, I don't see any. Any reference/approach would be helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no out of box support in either Swagger related libraries or Swagger UI for this.

There are couple of options:

1. Use extension/plugin options provided by `Springfox` to read your controller metadata and add the supported filter fields to your query parameter description. It supports `markdown`.
2. Use vendor extension properties so that it passes supporting information via Swagger YAML/JSON. Then, customize swagger UI to read that information and show some dynamic drop downs in Swagger UI.